# Change text in dynamically created p element from adobe animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Adobe animate creates the text elements with javascript when the page is loaded. I need to replace the text from Adobe animate with a variable text which I get from the URL (GET).

The element which is created from adobe animate (edge_includes/edge.6.0.0.min.js):

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#Stage_Titel p').text('Change Text!');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Stage_Titel">
    <p>Text to Replace!</p>
</div>
```

But the text won't change. What is wrong? Can I handle this by the jquery on the event?

Comment: Typo: `#Stage_Titel` is not the same as `#Stage_titel`

Comment: is the typo in your code as well ?

Comment: Its not the typo sorry. The problem is that the #Stage_Titel is created by another js-file. And now i cant do anything with it (hide, change...). I changed that thx.

Comment: Make sure that `#Stage_Titel` isn't inside a frame.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
       $("#Stage_titel").html("<p>Change Text!</p>")
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Stage_titel">
    <p>Text to Replace!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't works since jquery selectors are case-insensitive, the selector in  :

```
$('#Stage_Titel p').text('Change Text!');
__________^
```

Should be :

```
$('#Stage_titel p').text('Change Text!');
```

Note the `T` should be in lower case `t` format.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your Jquery selector. The id is `Stage_titel` not `Stage_Titel`

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#Stage_titel p').text('Change Text!');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Stage_titel">
    <p>Text to Replace!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#Stage_titel').text('Change Text!');
    });
```